# How do I recover a Windows 10 encryption key from an old hard drive?

Tags: windows-10, encryption, certificate, efs

I recently upgraded an OS hard drive and did a clean install of windows on the new drive. I have a secondary (non-OS) hard drive that stayed in the computer untouched. It appears there's a folder on it that was encrypted by EFS. Right clicking the folder > Properties > Advanced and unchecking "Encrypt contents to secure data" does not work and gives an error.

I've got no idea how this folder was encrypted (I assume I did it a looong time ago). Fortunately, I still have the previous OS drive that has not been touched. I booted into the Windows install on that drive and opened certmgr to export the key. However, under Personal > Certificates, there are no certificates present. Is there somewhere else it could be?

Comment: Without the ability to export the certificate realistically you cannot retrieve the certificate responsible for encrypting the files.

Comment: I understand. But would it only be listed in that location or somewhere else? When I switched drives a few months ago the original drive/OS had access to the files just fine.

Comment: The certificate would have only been in the personal certificates on the account that encrypted the folder in the first place. If that account is no longer accessible (and they didn't go through the process of saving a backup certificate somewhere else), the certificate is gone.

Comment: Actually...I located the key in the Trusted People > Certificates folder. I exported it and imported to the new computer. The thumbprints match, but I still can't read the files. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: You were able to install that certificate on the new machine?  Should have required a password

Comment: If you could do what you want it would render encryption useless.